# SQL server восстановление с дифференциального бэкапа

Tags: sql, sql-server, резервное-копирование

Снял фулл бэкап затем дифф бэкап. Допустим после снятия дифф бэкапа в базе происходят изменения. Можно ли после этих изменений откатить базу на момент снятия дифф бэкапа без восстановления всей базы (фулла)? Полное восстановление - долго.

Comment: Нельзя без логов. Проще чтоб вы понимали -> мотать вперед можно дифами и\или логами, мотать назад - только логами(и то не всегда).

Answer (score 1):

Нет. Чтобы восстановить базу на момент *снятия дифф бэкапа* нужно взять последний фул до этого дифа, и этот самый диф до которого вы хотите откатиться.